# How do I display the data returned from my API?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, api

I'm trying to display the ID and Document number returned from an array.

[Data Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP6H8.png)

As you can see this returns nothing
[Applicaton Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqclF.png)

I have tried string interpolation {{document.id}}} and {{ocument.documentNumber}}. I also have the interface set up id: string, documentNumber: string. This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item" *ngFor="let document of documents">
    <div>Document ID: {{ document.id }}</div>
    <div>Document Number: {{ document.documentNumber }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My GET method:

```
   public getDocuments(): Observable<Documents[]> {
        let url = this.config.url;
        if (!url.endsWith("/")) {
            url += "/";
        }
        console.log("getDocument URL:", `${url}api/v1/document/`);
        return this.http
            .get<Documents[]>(`${url}api/v1/document/`, {
                headers: {
                    authorization: this.config.authorization,
                },
            })
            .pipe(
                map((data) => {
                    console.log("getDocument:", data);
                    return data;
                }),
                catchError((error) => {
                    console.log("getDocuments Error:", error);
                    throw error;
                })
            );
    }
```

My component:

```
export class DocumentListComponent implements OnInit {
    public documents: Documents[] = [];

    public constructor(private aService: AService) {
        console.log("DocumentListComponent constructor", aService);
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("DocumentListComponent ngOnInit");
        this.aService.getDocuments().subscribe((documents: Documents[]) => {
            console.log("Received Documents:", documents);
            this.documents = documents;
            console.log("DocumentListComponent ngOnInit", this.documents);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to access `document.document.id` and `document.document.documentNumber` as they are nested on a `document` object within each array item.